Cannot Move Comments to Chat
At the request of Spevacus, I am posting this here.  Earlier today, I attempted to move the comments below Proof that a finite field isn't ordered. chat, and encountered the following error:

Now, a couple of hours later, I still cannot move the comments to chat, but am met with the error "Comments from this post have already been copied to chat previously."  So the messages have been moved to chat, but the automatic link to the chat was not generated in the comments.

Other moderators have reproduced this issue, so I'm tossing status-review at this. There's potential for this to be related to the chat upgrade, so I think it's pretty relevant. At the very least, this is a recent bug.

I just moved comments to chat without error.

@Laurel perhaps your diamond is stronger? ;) (Or, balpha fixed it already. :))

This was another consequence of this bug. Chat successfully imported the comments and responded as such, but because of that JSON encoding issue, math.se didn't understand that response and gave a generic error message (and also didn't post the automatic comment because it didn't know the import was successful).
On your later attempts, Chat responded with "Those comments have already been imported", but once again that response didn't arrive as expected, giving you the same non-descript error.
Once I had fixed that bug on Friday, that message came through, which is why you eventually received the correct response.
